# How do Typescript/ES6 imports behave with multiple class instances or component calls?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is a React component that renders stuff using values from a json file:

```
import React from 'react';
import jsonFile from 'file.json';
const Component = ({ thing }: { thing: string }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...json file is used in here...
    </div>
  );
};
```

This component will be called many times when the app runs.

Does `jsonFile` get reimported every time the component is called? What about classes, abstract classes, etc.? Is there ever a situation in React or in general where every new instance/call of a class/component causes a reimport to occur or are imports always loaded once before code execution?

I have a feeling the latter is the right answer but I would appreciate an explanation or a link to an explanation of how imports behave regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You're almost correct, but you're missing one thing: you're almost certainly using a bundler, so imports are resolved at *build-time*, not runtime.

---

ECMAscript 6 code (including classes, arrow functions, and even that import statement) is not supported by many browsers and only support pure JavaScript files. Moreover, JSX syntax is not supported in browsers because it's not a part of the ECMAscript spec. There are other issues too, such as the fact that you can only import a `.js` file and nothing else.

For those reasons, most modern web applications (such as your own) use something called a **bundler** to convert ES6 into compatible, widely-supported ES5. Bundlers do a lot of things to your code (e.g. minification) but one of those steps is taking these external dependencies and adding them into your code.

If you have special logic, you can technically do this in a variety of ways (i.e. downloading them at runtime - this is known as code splitting) but most people use the default method - resolution at build-time.

What all this means is that when you import `file.json`, before your browser runs it, your bundler finds `file.json` in the filesystem and embeds the JSON contents into the JavaScript file. For example, this means if you update it on your server without rebuilding, it will not change in the browser. **As a side-effect, it means that reimporting the same file (or in this case, JSON file) will not cause any slowdown.**

---

A few extra notes: your original premise that the JSON file would be reimported by using the component multiple times is a bit flawed because even if none of this bundler stuff happened, the file would be imported into the `jsonFile` variable and stored in memory; nothing in the component would cause a re-import since the variable is already defined.

Lastly, TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript but only has an impact at build-time: it throws compilation errors if it can statically detect that you use types incorrectly, but if there are no errors it does no dynamic checking at runtime; it merely converts the code into pure JavaScript. Therefore, there is no need to mention using TypeScript except in the context of a type error because it is identical to JavaScript at runtime.

Hope this clears it all up for you!

Comment: Aha I did not think about the bundler - You have cleared it up wonderfully, thanks!